# Help with models based on measurements

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Two distances $\alpha$ and $\rho$ are chosen equally likely (with equal probability) and independently in the interval of ordered distances in increasing order $[0; x]$. Calculate the probability that they are at a distance greater than $\gamma \in [0; x]$, knowing that the sum of both is greater than $x$.

Hint: Use the construction of probability models based on measurements.

I've been researching the suggestion/hint in the problem, but I can't figure out what it refers to. In this course we were just told that it is the $σ$-algebra and nothing about models.

My question is how do I come up with a model like the one they suggest and what characteristics do these models have?

Comment: You're selecting two numbers independently, a natural model is $[0,x] \times [0,x]$, events determine regions in that set and probabilities are calculated as areas.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So that would be a measurement-based model?. If I give myself an $a∈[0;x]$, $c∈[0;x]$ and $b∈[0;x]$, with mutually exclusive $a,b,c$, and $P()$, the probability I am looking for then $P()=ab$ ? how could I relate the restriction that an $a>c$, $b>c$ and $a+b>x$ ?